# Slow MicroSD card

Tags: filesystem, performance, sd-card

I've recently bought a 64GB MicroSD class10 card. Now according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Speed_Class_Rating), it should be able to transfer files at a rate of max 10MB/s. But I am only reaching 6.7MB/s (two-third of the promised speed):

[image: Slow speed]

I've formatted the card to FAT32, but I was wondering if formatting it to another file system would increase the transfer rate. One condition: the file system on the card needs to be usable by android (Samsung Galaxy S4 in particular).

**The formatting options:**

[image: formatting options]

Are they maybe any other solutions to speeding up the SD card?

Comment: You even said it's a max... You're not likely to see the max for very long if it all. You'll never see it when there are multiple files being transferred. You might come close if it is one big file and the card is fairly empty (allowing the one large file to fit onto contiguous space)

Comment: @DrakeClarris So you're saying that when I buy an SD card that can reach a 10MB transfer rate, I should be satisfied with 2/3 of that speed? I just suspected that the speed could be improved.

Comment: I have a 16GB class 10, and I only came close (around 9.5 or so) when copying a large, 6GB movie file to a card with barely 500 MB used. If I copy over 500 or so mp3s for example, I see about what you have stated.

Answer (score 0):

> transfer files at a rate of max 10MB/s

I think that when they said max is not meaning that that will be the fixed speed. Your problem may not be the filesystem used on the MicroSD card, it is a multitude of reasons that goes from your HDD performance, memory, cache, USB/MicroSD interface, CPU, etc. Meaning that it depends greatly in what your system general performance rather that a peculiar filesystem.

You instead of looking for ways to trying to reach the peak 10MB/s that the MicroSD card offers (again they say **maximum speed** not **fixed speed**, since it can be less at any given time) I would look for a process using the I/O, CPU, cache. I would also try for `cp` and `rsync` to compare performance results.